# Swift 3.0 Error "Cannot convert value of type"

Tags: ios, swift3

I am migrating a large codebase to Swift 3.0.  I am generating an error `"Cannot convert value of type 'Array<MultivalueEntry<Date>>?' to type 'AnyObject' in coercion.`

[image]

I've even tried setting newValue to `'Array<MultivalueEntry<Date>>?'` below, and it is still generating an error:
[image]

And lastly tried setting newValue to `'Array<MultivalueEntry<NSObject>>?'` with no success:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE MultiValueEntry:

```
public struct MultivalueEntry<T> {
    public var value : T
    public var label : String?
    public let id : Int

    public init(value: T, label: String?, id: Int) {
        self.value = value
        self.label = label
        self.id = id
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an array of generics cannot be converted to an NSArray or CFArray, because Objective-C knows nothing of generics. Well, a `MultivalueEntry<Date>` is a generic.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Matt.  How would I go about fixing this if I want to update this to Swift 3.0?

Comment: I don't know because you have not explained what a MultivalueEntry is. Why are you even using it? If this is about the Contacts / AddressBook, you should abandon the AddressBook framework and use the Contacts framework.

Comment: I am using the SwiftAddressBook, and Im trying to update my project to Swift 3.0.  Unfortunately SwiftAddressBook is not supported in Swift 3.0, so I am manually updating it.  I've had much success with SwiftAddressBook in iOS9, I'm using it to grab information from the users contacts.  I would love to stick with it, but if I can't use it I will try the Contacts Framework.

Comment: I've also updated my question with the MultiValue struct.

Comment: AddressBook is _deprecated_.

Comment: Crap, youre right.  Big oversight.  Looks like I have to update my project to Contacts